# Can't change vscode font

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

The problem is that I have the font installed in my pc, but when I change it in the settings, it sets a weird font

[image]

The font that i want is Iosevka
Json settings:

[image]

Comment: Most likely the font name is a bit different. Open the font file in a font viewer and look what the name is of the font, or use a tool like photoshop and see the names of the fonts installed (and a few of Adobe extra) See https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka/releases all names have some additional text

Comment: Choose the best `Stylistic Set` (`ss..`) for optimal difference between lower case L (`l`) and One (`1`)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been late to reply and maybe you have found out the answer for it but here is what I think could be wrong with the code.

1. First check if you have given the name of the font corerct or not by going into the Font Settings.
2. Second, font names such as MS Gothic or SourceCodePro-Medium should be in inside a double quote and the font name (i.e. MS Gothic and SourceCodePro-Medium) in single quote, also to be sure type monospace at last.
3. Third, be mindful of the space you give.

And if you think everything is alright then close VS Code and then open it again!